# java.net.SocketException : permition denied on simulator for socket program

Tags: sockets

java.net.SocketException : permition denied . on simulator for socket program.

When i am executing the program from simulator for socket it throws java.net.SocketException : permition denied exception but when i am running same code on the tablet, it get response from the socket server.
 Do i have to setup anything to run socket program using simulator??

Comment: Problem is resolved now.. 

we have to update Manifest file by allowing security level to internet outside the application tag.


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved now..

we have to update Manifest file by allowing security level to internet outside the application tag.